# Faulty Parallelism3: to 'while' or not to 'while'

Tags: parallelism

The problem sentence:

> I have always liked thinking through complicated problems to find
>   creative solutions, **be they in a mathematics class or while
>   helping a friend**.

I wrote this sentence for a personal statement; however, someone pointed out that the portion after the comma (bold) was incorrect. He said that the phrases on each side of the 'or' should be parallel in structure. So, if I was using 'in a mathematics class' (a prepositional phrase) before the 'or', I should use a prepositional phrase after the 'or' as well. He recommended that I drop the 'while' altogether (because it's not a preposition) or replace it with a preposition. Is he correct or should I leave the sentence as is?

Comment: Many contemporary grammarians, including the widely followed *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL)*, regard most of what traditional grammar treated as 'subordinating conjunctions' as prepositions. Many of these prepositions, however, are not used as predicatives or attributives, and that's the case with *while*: we don't say *He is **while** helping a friend*. In any case, the *while* is superfluous: its sense is inherent in the participial form.

Comment: @StoneyB has put his finger on the problem with the sentence. It's not lack of parallelism, but the construction *be they ... while helping a friend*. You can fix it by saying *whether in a mathematics class or while helping a friend,* which may still not have perfect parallelism, but doesn't have a glaring grammatical flaw.

Comment: @StoneyB I agree.  However, you might be able to get off the hook but substituting ‘it’ for ‘they’.  ‘it’ can be treated as referring to the activity of the verbal noun phrase.  I could be doing it either in a lesson or while helping a pal.

Comment: I'd put some serious muscle into rewriting it. I've read a ton of resumes, and this isn't helping your cause. "I like finding creative solutions to complex problems, whether in math class, or when helping a friend [some actual thing someone does that isn't drama, like, 'pick a major' or 'think through which college to attend']."

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks! You are right: 'while' is superfluous. Taking it out.

Comment: @Tuffy Good point. In that case the two PP, with *in* and *while*, modify the VP headed by *find* rather than the NP *creative solutions*.

Comment: I completely agree that the sentence should be rewritten if it is to be part of a CV, but I question the alleged lack of parallelism. What is not parallel about the two situations "in a ...class", "while helping a friend"? They both refer to particular occasions that might occur in someone's life.

Answer (score 1):

My main problem is that what follows the comma seems to be a misplaced modifier.

Although I believe *they* is referring to *complicated problems*, the closest noun to the pronoun is *creative solutions*. This causes some confusion.

---

If *they* refers to *complicated problems*, then I would reverse the sentence structure:

> Be they **encountered** in a mathematics class or while helping a friend, I have always liked thinking through complicated problems **in order** to find creative solutions **to them**.

Or you can leave the structure as it is but change the pronoun:

> I have always liked thinking through complicated problems to find creative solutions, be **it** in a mathematics class or while helping a friend.

Now, the pronoun is referring to the act of thinking (the only thing in the singular) rather than to either *complicated problems* or *creative solutions*.

---

In the unlikely event (to my mind) that *they* is actually referring to *creative solutions*, then I would make the following change:

> I have always liked thinking through complicated problems to find creative solutions, be **those solutions** found in a mathematics class or while helping a friend.

---

Of course, the specific wording to all of these can be easily changed. I am just pointing out the main ways of clarifying what's meant.

Comment: Interesting point. I  actually didn't think what  'they' was referring to - till now, that is. And it's the 'unlikely event'. lol. But I now see your point. Thank you for your updated version.